# My result is giving this while running the code: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas

```
FaultVersionsDict = {}
#nFirstFault = pd.read_csv("faults", sep=',')
for csvFile in dataFiles:
    nFirstFault = (pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep=',', nrows=0)).columns[:]  # the location of first fault
    # the first line of each file contains the zero-based index of the faulty statement
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep=',', header=None, skiprows=1)
    prMatrix = df.as_matrix()
    vFaultLocation[i] = nFirstFault
    vStatementCount[i] = prMatrix.shape[0]
    FaultVersionsDict[str(i)] = prMatrix
    i = i + 1
return [vFaultLocation, vStatementCount, FaultVersionsDict]
```

please help me. the first row on each of my all the csv files is has one or more than 5 columns while from second row, it has only four columns each. The first row is actually meant to do some other computation. Please help me

Comment: what is the error? show the data as well.

Comment: Also you should have a stacktrace telling you which function in which line went wrong. This would be helpful in this case.